# Change colors in Calendar Heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, rcharts, htmlwidgets

I am using a package called `rChartsCalmap`. This is the following code and output:

```
library(devtools)
install.packages('htmlwidgets')
install.packages(c("curl", "httr"))
install_github("ramnathv/rChartsCalmap")
library(rChartsCalmap)
```

Example found here:

https://github.com/ramnathv/rChartsCalmap

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
xts_to_df <- function(xt){
  data.frame(
    date = format(as.Date(index(xt)), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    coredata(xt)
  )
}

dat = xts_to_df(AAPL)
calheatmap('date', 'AAPL.Adjusted', 
           data = dat, 
           domain = 'month',
           legend = seq(500, 700, 40),
           start = '2014-01-01',
           itemName = '$$'
)
```

[image]
How do I change the color so that it is from red to green with a nice transition?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps http://durtal.github.io/calheatmapR/chLegend.html might help

Answer (score 0):

## calheatmapR

This solution uses [`calheatmapR`](https://github.com/durtal/calheatmapR) which allows a more complete range of options.  However, `calheatmapR` still requires quite a bit of manual manipulation.

## Prices?

I assume your provide `AAPL` data for reproducibility.  Using prices instead of `ROC` does not make much sense to me, but I use prices in my example to stick with your original example.  As I warned, some ugly manual manipulation is required to get data in the correct format.

## One Calendar Heatmap

I will start by making a calendar heatmap for one year.

```
# devtools::install_github("durtal/calheatmapR")
library(calheatmapR)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL")

aapl_list <- lapply(as.vector(AAPL[,6]), identity)
names(aapl_list) <- as.character(
  as.numeric(index(AAPL)) * 60 * 60 * 24 +
  6 * 60 * 60 # timezone adjustment (I am in GMT - 6)
)

calheatmapR(data = aapl_list) %>%
  chDomain(
    domain = "month",
    subDomain = "day",
    start = (as.numeric(as.Date("2016-01-01")) * 24 * 60 * 60 + 6 * 60 * 60) * 1000,
    range = 12
  ) %>%
  chLabel(position = "top", itemName = "") %>%
  chLegend(
    legend = pretty(quantile(AAPL[,6],seq(0,1,.1))),
    colours = list(
      min = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n=9,"Blues")[1],
      max = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n=9,"Blues")[9],
      empty = "#424242"
    )
  )
```

## All Years

I assume you would like to make a calendar heatmap for each year, so the next bit of code will employ a quick function, so that we can accomplish this.

```
# now let's make a function so we can one for each year
library(htmltools)
year_map <- function(year) {
  aapl_list <- lapply(as.vector(AAPL[year,6]), identity)
  names(aapl_list) <- as.character(
    as.numeric(index(AAPL[year,])) * 60 * 60 * 24 +
      6 * 60 * 60 # timezone adjustment (I am in GMT - 6)
  )
  
  tags$div(
    tags$h1(year),
    calheatmapR(data = aapl_list, height = "auto") %>%
      chDomain(
        domain = "month",
        subDomain = "day",
        start = (as.numeric(as.Date(paste0(year,"-01-01"))) * 24 * 60 * 60 + 6 * 60 * 60) * 1000, # in milliseconds with time zone adjustment
        range = 12
      ) %>%
      chLabel(position = "top", itemName = "") %>%
      chLegend(
        legend = pretty(quantile(AAPL[,6],seq(0,1,.1))),
        colours = list(
          min = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n=9,"Blues")[1],
          max = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n=9,"Blues")[9],
          empty = "#424242"
        )
      )
  )
}

browsable(
  tagList(
    lapply(
      unique(format(index(AAPL),"%Y")),
      function(yr) {year_map(yr)}
    )
  )
)
```

[image: partial screenshot]

## Thoughts

While the above "works", there are still many areas of improvement.  I will leave those to you.